# gnu screen via putty split -v right display coming up on left side

Tags: debian, ubuntu-14.04, putty, gnu-screen

We needed yet another screen question right?  This one is only regarding **VERTICAL** Splits.

Im on Trusty Tahr

```
$ screen -v
Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06
```

When i split vertically `split -v`, it appears to look normal.  The **right** pane works out of the box.  However, no matter if full screen or windowed, once i tab over to the **right** pane, it shows the terminal prompt, and what im typing, 
but once executed...

**the output pops up in the left pane,**

...overwriting over the top of it and cluttering it.

This leaves the right hand side empty of that output, where you can still see the terminal prompt, but there's a **green cursor artifact** sitting there about two lines below(the end of what would have been the original output), where it left and popped over to the left side.

So, is there something inherently wrong with split pane -v that's causing this right hand side to corrupt, or could it be my putty settings?

Here is my config, note the bindings werent for this particular setup, then can easily be changed to focus left/right.

```
#.screenrc  
startup_message off
vbell off
nonblock on     
altscreen on  
hardstatus message
#COMMENTING test for display issues
caption string "%{= kw}%Y-%m-%d;%c %{= kw}%-Lw%{= kG}%{+b}[%n %t]%{-b}%{= kw}%+Lw%1`"


# SCROLLBACK
defscrollback 10000

# BINDINGS
defbce "on"
bind 'K' kill
bind 'W' windowlist
bind 'V' split -v
bindkey -k k8 focus up
bindkey -k k9 focus down
```

And the screens

```
 #The split screen config
  screen -f -A -a -t 2col-l 1
  #shell -$SHELL
  split -v
  focus right
  #screen -f -A -a -t 2col-r 2
  screen -a -t 2col-r 2
  focus left
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great solution to alot of putty / screen (with and without vim) errors through putty.  It turned out it was the putty settings, especially the terminal type, but some other settings all wisely detailed here http://swhig.web.unc.edu/vim/.

If you slim down your putty settings to whats there, your pretty much good.

The useful settings were removing all putty customizations, creating a new profile from scratch, adding the following

```
Window -> Colours -> Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode
Connection > Data -> Terminal-type string -> putty-256color
```

and

```
Window > Appearance -> font consolas greatly helped the readibility, not sure if that helped with the issue or not.
```